# Finding correct selector using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to identify the correct selector using jQuery. I'm trying to hide/show a div depending on the selection of the user.

```html
      <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1v">
        <div class="active-panel-tab">
          <%= render 'dropdown_grid_selection' %>
          <%= render 'one_box' %>
          <%= render 'two_box' %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Then in this partial I have a dropdown selector box that a user can choose 1, 2, or 3 boxes. If they select one the two box option should be hidden.

```js
$('a > #one_box').click(function() {
  $('.tabs-panel.is-active > .active-panel-tab').hide('.two_box_wrapper')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown_grid">
  <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu data-alignment="right">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x"></a>
      <ul class="pane_choice menu vertical medium-horizontal">
        <li><a href="#" id="one_box">1 Box</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="two_box">2 Boxes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="three_box">3 Boxes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but I suspect the selector you want is `$('.tabs-panel.is-active > .active-panel-tab .two_box_wrapper')`

Comment: `'a > #one_box'` selects `#one_box` inside an `<a>`, which is incorrect according to your HTML. Since an ID is a _highly_ specific selector, just select with that instead: `$('#one_box')`

Comment: You need to be more specific but I can tell you the selector a> #one_box is wrong te CSS selector > work if a was the direct parent of #one_box, try delete the selector > and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("ul.pane_choice>li>a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idPart = $(this).attr("id"),currEle=$("." + idPart + "_wrapper"),
    divs = $(".tabs-panel>.active-panel-tab>div").not(currEle);       
    divs.hide();
    currEle.show();
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/697k4b8v/13/)

Answer (score 0):

If you view the HTML in chrome, open developer tools. You can then right-click an element in the elements-panel and click Copy->selector to find a selector that will point to that element. Continue from there by experimenting with that selector in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to hide the other two boxes that have not been selected. I think an if else statement should do.Like on clicking box1, hide box2 and 3 using thier IDs